# Creating a Virtual Environment on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python

I'm following instructions to create a Virtual Environment but it's not working properly. I think it wants to install pip but some setting is blocking it?  Any help would be appreciated!

Here's what I'm doing:

```
pyenv virtualenv my_first_env # create an environment
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
equirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (16.5.0)
pyenv: virtualenv: command not found
ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python.

Python modules For the system python are usually handled by dpkg and apt-get.

    apt-get install python-<module name>

Install the python-pip package to use pip itself.  Using pip together
with the system python might have unexpected results for any system installed
module, so use it on your own risk, or make sure to only use it in virtual
environments.

Installing pip from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py...
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/fb/863012b13912709c13cf5cfdbfb304fa6c727659d6290438e1a88df9d848/pip-19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.1
    Uninstalling pip-18.1:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

error: failed to install pip via get-pip.py
```

Additional details:

```
pyenv install 3.7.3
(Doesn't install.)
```

Pyenv:

```
pyenv --version
pyenv 1.2.11
```

Python:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Pip:

```
pip --version
pip 18.1
```

Virtualenv:

```
pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (16.5.0)
```

Comment: Have you installed `pyenv-virtualenv`?

Comment: It says in the instructions to install "pyenv", and "virtualenv", but nothing about "pyenv-virtualenv". Does it rely on a certain version of Python? (Also I added additional details above.)